# How can I make the user login only by clicking the confirmation link inside their mail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I integrated the devise "confirmation" module in my rails app. And I want a user to only login after clicking in the confirmation link provided in their email. But, a user is being redirected directly to the intended page right after sign up(without login).

Comment: Can you share some code? According to this Guide: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users - you need to call `sign_in(resource)` in the controller override configuring the redirect.

Comment: It worked after I comment  the following option inside initializers/devise.rb   "config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 365.days"

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? With this option devise will allow new users to sign in without ever having their emails confirmed - for 365 days.

Comment: I mean it was uncommented before, then I comment out that line, disabling the unconfirmed access